# replacing rows with no primary key mysql

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables. table A and table B as shown in the picture along with desired result:

[image]

The combination of id1 and id2 is unique. I want to replace the contents of the rows of table A with those in table B ( as seen in the desired result, the amount in row 1 and row 4 has been changed to reflect that in table B while retaining other rows of table A). What would be the best way to achieve this? Can REPLACE be used here ( with no single column as primary key).

Comment: You have a primary index on both key's correct? If that's the case, yeah, simply use replace into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want result by `SELECT`, try this:

```
SELECT 
    a.id1, a.id2,
    COALESCE(b.name1, a.name1) AS name1,
    COALESCE(b.name2, a.name2) AS name2,
    COALESCE(b.amount, a.amount) AS amount
FROM tablea a
LEFT JOIN  tableb b
ON a.id1 = b.id1 AND a.id2 = b.id2
```

If you want it by `UPDATE`, try this:

```
UPDATE tablea a
LEFT JOIN  tableb b
ON a.id1 = b.id1 AND a.id2 = b.id2
SET 
    a.name1 = COALESCE(b.name1, a.name1),
    a.name2 = COALESCE(b.name2, a.name2),
    a.amount = COALESCE(b.amount, a.amount)
```